# Emacs ESS: How to launch plots on Quartz window instead of X11 ?

Tags: r, emacs, plot, x11, quartz-graphics

I am using Macbook pro. I just started using ESS package in Emacs. I can plot graphs in ESS, however it launches a X11 application for plotting, which I personally think does not look as nice as the plots I get with the original R software.

The picture below shows the X11 device plotted by ESS on the left and the Quartz device plotted by original R software on the right.
[image]
**Question is:**  how can I make ESS launch the Quartz device everytime I execute a plot command instead of the X11 application ?